# How do I make certain functions that can be subscribed to without events (like Unity does)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, abstract-class

In Unity, when you make a new `MonoBehaviour` class, it comes with a whole load of functions that you can hook onto easily - for example `Update()`, `FixedUpdate()` and `Awake()`. I'm making my own component-entity system and I'm trying to add a range of functions that can easily be hooked onto by the components I create. I've made my base class abstract and have `Update` and `Draw` as abstract functions that can then be inherited. This works fine, apart from the fact that *all* my components have to implement all of those functions; something like Initialize would be useful for some components but not others and I'm not sure how to emulate this behaviour.

Is it done with reflection?

Comment: I guess you could use reflection for that, but for an easier out-of-the-box solution, you could take a look at "SendMessage": http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining your methods as *abstract*, you can define them as *virtual* and *override* them only when necessary.

```
class BaseComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void OnAwesomeEvent()
    {
        // do nothing or implement default behaviour
    }
}

class ShinyComponent : BaseComponent
{
    public override void OnAwesomeEvent()
    {
        Debug.Log("I've been waiting for this!");

        // If you need the default implementation you can call it with
        // base.OnAwesomeEvent()
    }
}

class LazyComponent : BaseComponent
{
    // I do nothing and no one cares
}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about that! Stupid... Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:

> I'm making my own component-entity system and I'm trying to add a
>   range of functions that can easily be hooked onto by the components I
>   create.

I don't particularly like the unity's "magic methods" approach on this. I think that implementing `interfaces` or `overriding virtual functions` could be often a cleaner solution. 
I used Unity's approach once, for an AI plugin which should call user defined methods without forcing to extend a class (basically because I had to avoid recompiling the code while modifying AI's behaviours)

In any case, for what concern the implementation:

**1) Send Message**

[SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) use a pure reflection implementation: the target method name can be know only when `SendMessage` is called.
This seems convenient (and might be perhaps, I still never used nor I felt the need to), but has several drawbacks:

1. **Performance**: reflection is costly (check some benchmarks, it ends up to be hundred of times slower than a direct method call)
2. **Not Type Safe**: can't check at compile time if the argument passed is of the right type.

**2) MonoBehaviour Messages**

Those methods (like `Awake`, `Update`, `OnCollision`, ...) are slightly different, because Unity can know the signature and compile the delegates. (I'm not sure of the implementation, but I've done something similar).

The way to go, to implement something similar is well described in this [article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/).
Basically you use reflection only in initialization, but once obtained the `MethodInfo`, you can compile the method as a delegate with `Delegate.CreateDelegate`.

Results:

- You still use reflection, but only in initialization
- Once compiled, the delegate is almost as fast as a standard method call (or event).

Comment: Thanks, this is a really useful guide :)